# disable clickable landmark on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map API v3. I want to disable click action on default google landmark/poi. For example, when I zoom to UCLA, the school icon shows up (that's fine) but I don't want user to click and view details of that location. Which API function should I use?

Comment: I found an example on airbnb map search. They disabled the landmark click without hiding landmarks. How did they do it?

Comment: I think you can force an earlier version of their api, like say 3.3 or 3.4, and it might work, or you can use the solution I posted below with the latest api.

Answer (score 54):

Google has exposed an option for this. See `clickableIcons` of `google.maps.MapOptions` [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions).

Example initialization code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    clickableIcons: false
});
```

Answer (score 18):

add this option to mapOption
clickableIcons: false

this is more options i think you will

```js
draggable: true, // this is for disable the Draggable
disableDefaultUI: true, // this for disable Default UI
fullscreenControl: false, // this is for disable Full Screen
scrollwheel: true, // this is for disable Scroll Wheel
disableDoubleClickZoom: false, // this is for disable Double Click Zoom
draggableCursor:'crosshair',// this is for cursor type
draggingCursor:'move', // this is for dragging cursor type
minZoom: 3, // this is for min zoom for map
maxZoom: 18 , // this is for max zoom for map
//note : max, min zoom it's so important for my design.
zoom: 14, // this is to make default zoom
clickableIcons: false, // this is to disable all labels icons except your custom infowindow or Infobox.
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this same problem.
Google appears to have recently changed their api to make the base map labels "clickable" and there is not yet a simple API call to disable their clickablility. 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/f1ac9ad4da3606fe

I would like to see google add a simple map option like this, but alas it doesn't exist yet

```
var opts = { clickableLabels:false };
var map = new maps.google.com.map(div,opts);
```

The following solution works, but because it relies on custom styled map tiles, free maps are limited to (2,500 maps loads per day) - [See Google Maps FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html).

```
function initialize() {

  // For more details see 
// http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html
  var noPOILabels = [
    { 
      featureType: "poi", 
      elementType: "labels", 
      stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] 

    }
  ];

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var noPOIMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(noPOILabels,
    {name: "NO POI"});

  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'no_poi']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('no_poi', noPOIMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('no_poi');
}
```

Comment: Just reading this, it looks like it would completely hide the markers rather than simply making them not clickable.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. For an unofficial (unstable) solution that leaves them visible see my comment under the question above about forcing a earlier API version. If you find a better solution I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been logged with google at:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3866

Please star and comment your needs on this issue there.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the OP wants a solution that persists the labels/icons but suspends the click events. I'm not sure this is possible; please [star this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3866)

However, some of us are drawing shapes sans Drawing Manager and labels/icons are obstructing the additions of new points. If it meets your requirements, you can temporarily remove the icons/labels. I've found that *transit*, *poi*, and *landscape* all need to be toggled:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {});
map.poi = function(state){

  var styles = [
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
      ]
    },{
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
      ]
    },{
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  this.set("styles", (state)? {} : styles );

}
```

And the usage:

```
//turn the labels/icons off
map.poi(false);

//turn them back on
map.poi(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is old, but maybe this answer will help others:

I'm not sure if this is legal, but I ended up exploring the code and made this:

```
$("#google-map").on("mousedown",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        disableInfoWindows();
    },500);
});

function disableInfoWindows()
{
    $(".gm-iw.gm-sm").parent().parent().remove();
    $("[style='position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;']")
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .remove();
}
```

It worked for me, no infoWindow showing up, while preserving all the icons. Anyone who has an idea enhancing the code is welcome, the infoWindow is showing up just a bit the first time it is about to open, after that first one, it is completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the other solutions work but you can also want to have ability to hide/disable only part of that pins or disable ability to go to details from popups, please see my post here with some tips how you can do that [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74363633/7666033)

> Right, to sum up, if you want to "remove" popups, you can just use:
>
> > clickableIcons: false
>
> for map options object. But if you want to have a popup, but without "View on Google Maps" label, you can use a hacky CSS trick:
>
> > google-map {
> > .view-link {
> > display: none !important;
> > }
> > }
>
> That was my requirements, and it works!
>
> If you want to define which icons/pins (elements or labels, however you call it) should be visible, you can use this site to generate proper JSON with map settings: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/