# How to safely remove google maps from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dom, cordova

I am developing an app with phonegap and because of the way it works with mobile framework, where everything / every page is on a single document, I'd like to be able to safely remove a google map from the DOM when I need to display another map for another purpose.

I believe doing something like `$("selectorforGmap").empty()` is not the best practice.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: "safely" in which context (avoiding memory leaks)?

Comment: yes, as well as making sure no script is still running on the background and no variables / objects are kept in memory

Comment: I'm afraid there is no good solution, see: [Google Maps JS v3 - detached DOM tree - memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142483/google-maps-js-v3-detached-dom-tree-memory-leak). I think the best you can do is to use  use the same Map-instance for all pages

Comment: Maybe it's useful for you: [What is the Proper Way to Destroy a Map Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485582/what-is-the-proper-way-to-destroy-a-map-instance)