# google maps api v3 javascript click only markers

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

I have a problem i am using google maps api v3 in phonegap with jquery mobile and set up markers but i want to be able to click only them but i am able to click destinations on the map such as hospitals. how i can disable the option leaving only the markers clickable?
also i need to close open infowindows when coming from different page and i am able to close infowindows of my markers but the hospital infowindow stays open.

how can i close the infowindows or dont let the user click anything else but the markers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close InfoWindow for local business marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335299/close-infowindow-for-local-business-marker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable clickable landmark on google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267789/disable-clickable-landmark-on-google-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable click behavior of POI markers in Google Maps v3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902829/disable-click-behavior-of-poi-markers-in-google-maps-v3-6)

Comment: You've been geocodezipped....