# Is it possible to disable gMap default markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to disable the default markers that come on Google maps?

I have checked on gmap3.net, which is the library I am using for creating the maps and also on the gMap API doc site but I can't seem to find any reference to disable this feature...

If you see the image below, throughout any map there are small icons representing places, e.g. parks, schools, malls, etc... Is there a way to disable these from appearing?

[image: I want to disable]

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable clickable landmark on google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267789/disable-clickable-landmark-on-google-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable click behavior of POI markers in Google Maps v3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902829/disable-click-behavior-of-poi-markers-in-google-maps-v3-6)