# Getting callback/location when user click on points of interest

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm interested in looking up establishments close to points on a map that a user selects by clicking.  I added a click handler to the map using  google.maps.event.addListener, which picks up the lat/lng of the clicked location.  Works great.

The problem is that the map has POIs that when clicked, don't fire the normal event and display their own infowindow, so I have no idea where the user clicked.  I can write some terrible code to inject content into the info window, but I'm not sure how to figure out the lat/lng of the POI.

In order of best solution to worst, I'd like to do one of the following:
1. Register for some kind of event to be notified when user click on POI, set my own content for the info window, and be notified of the lat/lng of POI.
2. Disable this infowindow for POIs, have the normal click handler fire.
3. Have the normal click handler fire when POI is clicked, as seen on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events
4. Disable the POIs from showing up.

Any advice?

Comment: The only option of your list that works is to disable the POIs. Related question: [disable clickable landmark on google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267789/disable-clickable-landmark-on-google-map)

Comment: Note that the demo at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events fires the click event when clicking on a POI, but I don't seem to have that happening in my app.

What are they doing differently?

Comment: That seems to only happen in their documentation.  [Fiddle containing the same code](http://jsfiddle.net/gg8zw5t4/), click event doesn't fire there.

Comment: Hmm, you're right =(.  Maybe someone from Google Maps will see this and comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it has something to do with the API version.

In the [Fiddle @geocodezip mentioned](http://jsfiddle.net/gg8zw5t4/), they load this API:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js`

However, if you look at the [documentation example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-events), they load these 2 scripts: 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true`

and
`https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/4/main.js`

And it seems like if I load the same scripts in the Fiddle, click on POI works.
I fork the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/1atqyuaz/).

hope this help.